# Unable to allocate partitions to USB

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, partitioning, storage

I recently received a USB. It worked fine for a while, then I formatted it using the `Format New Disk` menu in Windows. Now, it has a lot of unallocated memory. I know this is not a [fake USB drive](http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/-fake-usb-flash-memory-drives) because it worked earlier.

When viewing this in Disk Management, I see this:

[image]

However, I cannot allocate space to the unallocated partitions. When I right-click, this is what I get:

[image]

Additionally, right-clicking the label in the top menu gives this:

[image]

On all other disks (which work), I get something more similar to this:

[image]

Additionally, when viewed in File Explorer it looks different (It's disk E)

[image]

When trying to view it in File Explorer, I get this error:

[image]

Trying to use DIR in command prompt yields the same result:

[image]

How to I allocate the space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can always allocate the space, sadly, Windows cannot detect more than one partition in a USB Drive marked as Removable Drive. Besides, if you still want to create multiple partitions for any reason, there is a software named **EaseUS Partition Master** for Windows. Download it, install it, plug your USB drive, open the software and then,

> - Click over **EaseUs Partition Master Free** icon;
> - It will detect available drives as **Disk 1**, **Disk 2**, etc. Identify your USB stick by its size. If only primary HDD and USB Stick is connected, your drive would be **Disk 2**;
> - Right-Click on any partition of this drive and select **Delete/Resize/Format** (based on your needs);
> - Click **Apply** icon right below the General option in Menu Bar - [source](http://www.easeus.com/resource/partition-manager/free-partition-manager-software.htm);
> - You now will only be able to access the first partition you created in second last step - [source](http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/multipartufd);

My answer is based on `EaseUS Partition Master Free Edition 10.1`. Yours may differ.

#### About EaseUS Partition Master

> EaseUS Partition Master Free Edition is a free partition manager software. It offers a powerful range of functions such as resizing, formatting, copying, creating, deleting, hiding partitions and a handful other functions.

#### Where to download

> [Here](http://download.easeus.com/trial/epm_trial.exe) from http://www.easeus.com

Comment: I think it's very silly Windows only finds the first one, but your answer solved my problem. Thanks!